# A systematic method of counting all of the subsets of N or all of the numbers between (0,1)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, foundations

Could someone please point out errors in this reasoning?

I am aware and understand the points of both Cantor's diagonal argument and theorem, but:

Suppose we take an incremental list of sets of natural numbers, such as {1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, ... etc.

and then we form sets of subsets of each consecutive steps. In principle, we could account for all of the subsets that could be formed in the course of exhausting N in this way, although the number of those subsets does rise exponentially.

On the other hand, if we make a list of consecutively longer decimals such as 0.x, 0.xx, 0.xxx..., etc., in which 'x' is a placeholder for numbers, and we make a new list containing all of combinations of numbers 0-9 out of each of those elements on the original list, we would, if the lists continue to be filled up forever, account for all of the reals between 0 and 1.

Infinities in both of these cases are only potential, and it is assumed that the construction process could go on forever for it to yield the desired result.

What is wrong with this?
Thanks!

Comment: There are infinite subsets of $\Bbb{N}$ and infinite decimal fractions.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that those are said to be uncountable, in contrast to natural numbers. Although - by the above reasoning - they do seem in principle countable to me, just like the naturals.

Comment: I found this Question because I had the same Idea and have yet to find a convincing rationale as to why this mapping wouldn't work as it quite literally brute forces all possible combinations of numbers leaving none behind given an infinite depth of recursion. I suppose I'm missing something with Cantor's Diagonal Argument, but so far I am not convinced.

My only hunch as to why it's not possible would be that while N has infinitely many numbers, R has infinitely many infinitely long numbers. But "exhausting" N's infinity makes little intuitive sense.

Answer (score 3):

I'll focus first on the second argument. Your construction using decimals of the form 0.x, 0.xx, 0.xxx, etc. will exhaust all real numbers with finitely many decimal places, even if that finite number is arbitrary. This is a subset of the rational numbers. You need to consider reals with infinite precision. To give a concrete example, your construction will never output $\pi$.

With regards to subsets of the natural numbers, a similar thing is happening. Your algorithm will only ever output a finite subset of the natural numbers, and will never, for example, output the set of even natural numbers. In order for your procedure to work, it must output every possible subset of $\mathbb{N}$ at some point. Thus, you have to tweak your procedure to allow for the creation of infinite subsets. Cantor proved, however, that you will never be able to make this work.

Comment: True, although it would approximate it ever more closer with each consecutive step.

Comment: You are thinking of a geometric approximation, which is true. But set-theoretically, there is no such approximation happening.

Comment: That is peculiar, I have no idea how to construct a set containing any transcendentals with such finitary methods. But, could you explain a bit more on how this applies to the first argument above?

Comment: The first case is the same.  You get all the finite sets but none of the infinite ones.

Comment: How does one usually get an infinite set? N for example?

Comment: @KarloMikić It depends on the procedure you outline. For example, you can take your algorithm above and then apply an extra step that takes the complement, so the empty set becomes all of N, the set {1,2} becomes all of N besides for 1,2, etc. Then you are generating lots of infinite subsets, but you are missing all those infinite subsets whose complements are also infinite, etc. However you define the process, you will be missing most of the sets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ElchananSolomon! Yet, I don't find this procedure unsuccessful because at no point it outputs every possible subset of N. I don't find that task to be possible (or meaningful). I see no procedure that could output every possible element of N either. But what it does, is it gives a blueprint for a process, which, if it goes on forever, will not exclude any of the possible subsets in its course, at every consecutive step it will output all of the possible subsets for that point and increment that ad infinitum. It gives a rule which every such subset will conform to.

Comment: It is intensional in character. On the other hand, sets are extensional. Because of that I can see meaning in a rule specifying the construction of all naturals, but I find the notion of an extensional set containing an infinite amount of anything mind-boggling. So, I can speak of the 'set of natural numbers' only as a shorthand or as a symbol, a practical device to speak of properties holding for every single natural number. But if I take it as a set in the same way as some finite set, then I don't really know what to make of it exactly.

Comment: @KarloMikić  You write "sets are extensional", but mathematical set theory axioms like ZFC are largely about intensional definitions of what a set is.